# 301 redirects in nginx on laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, redirect, nginx, homestead

I'm trying to configure some 301 permanent redirects for some pages that have been moved (to a sub-folder of '/local').  My local environment, the test server and the live server all run on nginx, which I am new to.  My local environment is set up with Homestead and I am trying to get the redirects to work there first.

I have ssh'd to my homestead vm, and edited the file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:  I have added this server block within the http block:

```
    server {
        server_name local.kkds;

        location /essex {
            rewrite ^/essex(.*)$ /local/essex$1 permanent;
        }
    }
```

When I include the server_name and do `sudo nginx -s reload`, I get the message
`nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "local.kallikids" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`
The urls redirect but all pages display an nginx 404 page, except the homepage which displays 'Welcome to nginx' page.

If I comment out the server_name the rest of the site works as it should but the redirects don't happen.  I also tried replacing the server name with ip address in my homestead.yaml file and with 0.0.0.0 but still the redirect are not happening.

Perahps I am placing the configuration in the wrong place?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is an existing server? You need to find the file which defines the `server` block for that `server_name` and add your rewrites there. It will probably be in a file included into the `nginx.conf` file using an `include` directive.

Comment: That was it!  There was a file local.kkds in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.  I added the code inside the server block there and it works perfectly, thankyou!